# Kotlin Classes: should I have used custom get/set methods instead?

Tags: kotlin, class, interface, properties

I'm experimenting with class construction in Kotlin, as a beginner who has notwithstanding some knowledge of Java.

Whenever I want to try a new programming language, I try to build a class which generates the present tense conjugation of German verbs, based on two arguments: the infinitive and the 3rd person singular (he-person), from which the full conjugation can be predicted.

Based on the initial arguments, which are simultaneously two properties of each verb, the remaining properties (i.e. the remaining personal forms of the verb) are made. However, I don't even include the we-person and the they-person as standalone properties, because they are the same as the infinitive.

As such, I declare the following interface:

```
package myInterfaces

interface IGermanVerb {
    val firstPer : String // I-person, mostly predictable from the infinitive
    val secPer : String // You-singular-person, predictable from the he-person
    val fifthPer : String // You-plural-person, predictable from the infinitive

    fun printConjSum() // Conjugation summary: I, you-singular, he
    fun printFullConj() // Full conjugation
}
```

Then I implement it. For each grammatical person, I define the conditions for the creation of the full verb form, based on the endings of the infinitive and/or he-person:

```
package myClasses.classBuilds

import myInterfaces.IGermanVerb

open class GermanVerb(private val infin: String, private val thirdPer: String) : IGermanVerb {

    override val firstPer = if (infin.endsWith("en")) {
        infin.slice(0 until infin.length - 1)
        }
        else if (infin.endsWith("en")) {
            infin.slice(0 until infin.length - 1) + "e"
        }
        else {
            "??????"
        }

    override val secPer = if (thirdPer.endsWith("sst")) {
            thirdPer
        }
        else if (thirdPer.endsWith("t") && !thirdPer.endsWith("st")) {
            thirdPer.slice(0 until thirdPer.length - 1) + "st"
        }
        else {
            "??????"
        }

    override val fifthPer = if (infin.endsWith("en")) {
            infin.slice(0 until infin.length - 2) + "t"
        }
        else if (infin.endsWith("rn")) {
            infin.slice(0 until infin.length - 1) + "t"
        }
        else {
            "??????"
        }

    override fun printConjSum() {
        println("$infin: \n\t ich $firstPer \n\t du $secPer \n\t er $thirdPer")
    }
    override fun printFullConj() {
        println("$infin: \n\t ich $firstPer \n\t du $secPer \n\t er $thirdPer \n\t wir $infin \n\t ihr $fifthPer \n\t sie $infin")
    }
}
```

Then I define a derived class for a set of irregular verbs, whose persons conjugate slightly differently:

```
class GermanVerbModalIrregular(infin: String, thirdPer: String) : GermanVerb(infin, thirdPer) {
    
    override val firstPer = thirdPer

    override val secPer = if (thirdPer.endsWith("ss")) {
        thirdPer + "t"
    } else {
        thirdPer + "st"
    }

}
```

On a separate file, I create some instances of these classes:

```
package myClasses.classInstances

import myClasses.classBuilds.GermanVerb
import myClasses.classBuilds.GermanVerbModalIrregular


val essenVerb = GermanVerb("essen", "isst")
val sehenVerb = GermanVerb("sehen", "sieht")
val sterbenVerb = GermanVerb("sterben", "stirbt")

val sollenVerb = GermanVerbModalIrregular("sollen", "soll")
val wollenVerb = GermanVerbModalIrregular("wollen", "will")
val wissenVerb = GermanVerbModalIrregular("wissen", "weiss")
```

Finally, the main function:

```
import myClasses.classInstances.*

fun main() {
    essenVerb.printConjSum(); println()
    sehenVerb.printConjSum(); println()
    sterbenVerb.printConjSum(); println()

    sollenVerb.printFullConj(); println()
    wollenVerb.printFullConj(); println()
    wissenVerb.printFullConj(); println()
}
```

My directory structure:

[image: Directory]

On the console, the main() function returns the expected result:

[image: Console]

So, what's my question? Actually, I have the feeling that I'm doing something wrong. The "inner" properties of this class (not the initial arguments) are conditional, and they are supposed to return "?????" if the infinitive and the 3rd person singular don't obey the expected grammatical rules.

1. Should I encapsulate the conditional definition of these properties inside explicit get() and set() methods?
2. Should the infinitive and the 3rd person singular (the base arguments) be included inside the class body as properties that mimic the arguments' content?

Comment: Well what do you mean by *should*? Your code works, and you are asking for suggestions/advice on it? That's kind of opinion based and doesn't seem like an on-topic question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I thought that I may not be following the best practices. Or that it works in this case, but may not work for databases (for example). Anyway, thank you so much. I'll take your answer as proof that I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: @Sweeper There's a separate [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though that has very little Kotlin, and I personally don't have a problem with questions involving style here.

Comment: @swrutra I can't see any major issues. It might be slightly more concise with `when` blocks instead of `if`…`else` blocks, but that's minor. Also, in the Java world, it's not common to use an interface for every class; it's not worthwhile unless you reasonably expect multiple implementations. That's also why the `I…` prefix is rare: an implementation usually uses some relevant prefix (e.g. `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface using an array). If you can't think of a relevant prefix to distinguish that implementation from any others, then you probably don't need the interface! (contd.)…

Comment: Re. the title, you could indeed override the getters instead of using property initialisers; either is valid, but there's a trade-off: using a property initialiser takes more time at construction, and keeps the values (and references) in memory thereafter, but makes subsequent access trivial, and shows up any errors immediately — while custom getters are faster to construct and don't hold any unnecessary memory, but each access requires calculation and temporary memory. So the choice depends on the expected pattern of access. (contd.)…

Comment: …The code is almost identical for a custom getter: `override val firstPer get() = …`. Or you could compromise with lazily-initialised properties — Kotlin makes this trivially easy with [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#lazy-properties).

Comment: @gidds Actually, I don't know the real purpose of an interface yet. Someone told me that "it's a good practise". Is an interface just kind of a simplified overview of our future classes' properties?

Comment: @swrutra The point of an interface is to separate the, er, interface from the implementation: code that refers only to the interface can use _any_ implementation of that interface, without change. That can be really powerful — but it can be over-used. As I said, it's only worth creating an interface if there's a significant chance that you'll _want_ multiple implementations. (In my experience, that's not too common, though it depends on the type of project and how it's designed.) Otherwise, they're just pointless code that bulks up your project and makes it harder to navigate and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Where is no single answer to question you ask.

In kotlin you have many variants how to implement variable, for example:

```
val x = 1 // on-init, fixed
val y get() = x * 2 // on demand, evaluated
val z by lazy { y * x + 2 } // lazy, memoized
val q by myOwnProvider {...} // any property provider you can imagine
var onlyPlus : Int = 0    // semi-val , with private conditional setter
   private set(value) {
      if(value > field) {
        field = value
      }
   }
```

So you can decide:

1. if it's provided at ctor and will not ever changed - `val x = someparam`
2. if it's primitive type and it cannot be change - same
3. it causes large time to prepare and cosumes resources, but is used conditionally - `lazy`
4. it can be evaluated only just whole class instance initialized - `lazy`
5. it can be changed after instance creation and it's legal - only `get()`
6. you repeat and copy paste same large getters and setters - write your own provider and use `by` with it

Your choice should be based on behavior you try to get from your code it's not defined by some style-guide